# Is it possible to expand the scope of this site?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, moderation

As some people probably know, this is the 3rd iteration of a SE site proposal whose scope covers 3D printers. The first 2 were [Personal Manufacturing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22246/personal-manufacturing)(before my time) and [Digital Fabrication](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41850/digital-fabrication)(I tried and failed).

Now I am faced with a situation where I want to ask a question about DIY Polystyrene foam milling (I was researching a bit of [foam casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost-foam_casting) for a micro-hydro turbine wheel), and I don't have a convenient SE site to ask it.

So my question is that, is it possible to expand the scope of the 3DPrinting SE to a more general scope, in particularly 3D Milling, given that a LOT of the underlying tech IS shared?

I am asking this because a lot of the people involved in the first 2 failed proposals are participating here and may be able to help answer my questions (and further, despite the site's title, this [answer](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/143/150) advises a more inclusive approach).

*Minor Addendum: I would love being able to ask questions related to even [Dave Gingery's work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_J._Gingery) here, but that's a very long way off (It would've definitely been on-topic for Personal Manufacturing).*

Answer (score 4):

A quick reply for now (I might expand on it later).

Please see [Game plan - What is on-topic?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276/game-plan-what-is-on-topic). I've been trying to build a list for the On-topic page. I can add your suggestions to that list, if you like. Although CNC is already added to the list, but foam cutting isn't (yet). There were some questions asked about polystryrene cutting in [chat], from [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46947393#46947393) onwards. I don't think an actual question was posted though.

I agree with 0scar, that, IMHO, we shouldn't change the name as it might put people (3D enthusiasts) off, and we are attracting more and more hits everyday (albeit slowly), see [this answer](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264/what-does-it-take-to-get-out-of-beta-stage/265#265).

Answer (score 3):

Please look into [this question](/questions/147/hobbyist-machine-questions-on-topic), which is a similar question as you ask.

I think the general consensus is that CNC and laser cutting machines fall in the same category as 3D printers with respect to control, axis, modeling, etc. as the difference may be the tool the positioning head is carrying.

My general concern is if you want to include this, does the name of the site cover the content? "Makers.SE" is suggested, but that would include even more "hobbyist machines" that at least fall very much out of this scope (like the mentioned vacuum forming).

When we keep the name 3DPrinting, it should be about 3D printing, if the scope is extended (which is perfectly defendable for CNC machines and laser cutters based on similarity), the name should be changed (if that is possible).

I'm not in favor to change the name as it might scare people away or may cause people to not find the site. At the moment we are already doing everything we can to get out of the Beta phase.

Comment: I don't like the idea of a name change, at least for the main title. There has been reason given for changing the URL, as in so we can have posts show up in the chat, but that doesn't imply a site definition change.

Comment: How about 3D Automated Manufacturing, which covers additive and subtractive?